# Angular 6 GridDataResult' is not assignable to type 'Observable<GridDataResult>

Tags: angular

I am converting Angular 4 site to A6

I have a kendo grid and having trouble with the component to correctly get the service layer to call the api. I get the following error when

```
Type 'GridDataResult' is not assignable to type 'Observable<GridDataResult>'.
  Property '_isScalar' is missing in type 'GridDataResult'.
```

My component looks roughly like this...

```
  getIncomingViolations: Observable<GridDataResult>;

  constructor(private vioMappService: VioMappService, ) { }

  ngOnInit() {
    this.getIncomingViolations = 
    this.vioMappService.getIncommingViolations(this.mid)
      .pipe(map(res => this.getIncomingViolations = res));
  }
```

Service roughly looks like

```
export class VioMappService {

  constructor(private http: HttpClient) { }

  getIncommingViolations(mid: string): Observable<GridDataResult> {
    const params = new HttpParams()
      .set('mid', '1'),

    return this.http.get(AppSettings.API_ENDPOINT + 'MappViolations/MappViolations?', {params})
      .pipe(
        map((response: { incomingViolationList: any, incomingViolationListCount: any }) => ({
          data: response.incomingViolationList,
          total: response.incomingViolationListCount})
        )
      );
  }
}
```

And just for reference this is what the json I am getting looks like

```
{
    "incomingViolationList":[{"productName": "Rectangle Mirror",…],
    "incomingViolationListCount": 67
}
```

Comment: You are not subscribed the observables. Please check my answer

Answer (score 2, accepted):

- Change `Observable<GridDataResult>` to `GridDataResult` in your component.
- Subscribe your **getIncomingViolations** method

  ```
     getIncomingViolations: GridDataResult;
     constructor(private vioMappService: VioMappService, ) { }

     ngOnInit() {

      this.vioMappService.getIncommingViolations(this.mid)
        .subscribe((res:GridDataResult)=>{
                       this.getIncomingViolations = res;
                  });
    }
  ```

Comment: That did it. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

In the `map` function within your component, you're doing:

```
.pipe(map(res => this.getIncomingViolations = res))
```

Within `map`, the result will be unwrapped, i.e. it will no longer be an Observable-- it will be a `GridDataResult`. That means it cannot be assigned to `getIncomingViolations` which is typed as a `Observable<GridDataResult>`

Comment: So how would you do it? If I do `.pipe(map(res => res))` it still doesnt go to the url `AppSettings.API_ENDPOINT + 'MappViolations/MappViolations?'`

Comment: What is it you're trying to achieve with that line? You may not need any `.pipe` if you're happy with the structure that comes back from your service `getIncommingViolations`